# Draw the array referred by the reference u

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Draw the array referred by the reference `u`. I have drawn it as it shows on the picture link below. In order to fill the array `u` with values so i need some help with.
With the pincel and paper I got this values `u[0] = 3 , u[1] = 6 and u[2] = 10` which I'm not sure are correct.
Please if you answer this question do not only suggest value explain it step by step through the loop.

```
int[][] b = { {1, 2, 3},
              {2, 3, 4},
              {3, 4, 5} };

int[] u = new int[b[0].length];

for (int i = 0; i < u.length; i++){   
         u[i] = b[0][i];
    for (int j = 1; j < b.length; j++)
         u[i] += b[j][i];
    }
}
```

[The array drwan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i9Zl.png)

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: Do you want to know the values inside the array `u`, and someone explaining to you how to figure it out?

Comment: Sit down with a pencil and paper and work your way through it. It's not that complicated.

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve describe your problem in more detail to help you.

Comment: Yes, you can if you work through it on paper. Do you expect us to draw you a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
 u[0] = 6, u[1] = 9, u[2] = 12
```

I will explain how the loop goes.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < u.length; i++){   
       u[i] = b[0][i];
  for (int j = 1; j < b.length; j++)
       u[i] += b[j][i];
      }
```

First loop:

```
 outer for loop:
 u[i] = b[0][i]; --> u[0] = 1

 inner for loop:
 u[i] += b[j][i] --> u[0] += b[1][0] so --> u[0] = 1 + 2 --> u[0]=3

 second loop in inner for loop:

 "now j = 2"
  u[0] += b[2][0] --> u[0] = 3 + 3 --> u[0] = 6
```

that's how it does. Just repeat on u[1] and u[2]

Comment: `u[i] += b[j][i] --> u[0] += b[1][0] so --> u[0] = 1 + 2 --> u[0]=3` Isn't here out of both loop and the value of the first cell = 3 why 6

Comment: I think i understand it now the inner loop loops two times before going out of outer loop. ok Thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late response been busy yesterday at work. Glad that you found it out yourself.